# Using $_SESSION to carry a php variable from one page to the next?

Tags: php, html, variables, session

I created an app to receive and tally votes.  I am trying to make the voter's selection carry over to a confirmation page so that I can display the name of the candidate for whom they voted on the confirmation page.

I am trying to use $_SESSION on the variable of the selected candidate from the voter's submission, and then call the variable on the confirmation page, however I continue to get undefined variable error.

voterSubmit.php:

```
<?php
$selectedCandidate = $_POST['candidateid'];

session_start();
$selection = $_SESSION[$selectedCandidate];


//Redirect to results page
header("Location: views/confirmation.php");
```

confirmation.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION[$selectedCandidate] = $selection;

include "views/confirmation.php";
```

confirmation view:

```
<?php include "../partials/header.php"; ?>

<h1>Thanks For Your Vote!!</h1><br>
 //This is where the error occurs (on my selection variable):
<h2>You voted for <?=$selection?> 

<a href="results.php">View Results</a>


<?php include "../partials/footer.php"; ?>
```

I want the name of the selected candidate to appear on the confirmation page by way of the $selection variable.  However, all I receive on the front end is an "undefined variable" error.  I also would like to note that instead of using the $selectedCandidate variable in my session, I have also tried grabbing the name directly by just using the name of the radio button selection as such:

```
$_SESSION['candidateid'] = $selection
```

I also would like to mention that i have tried the reverse:

on confirmation.php:

```
session_start();
$selection = $_SESSION[$selectedCandidate];
```

on voteSubmit.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION[$selectedCandidate] = $selection;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

voterSubmit.php looks ok... but I don't understand why you have `include "views/confirmation.php";` *in the confirmation.php file*.

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION[$selectedCandidate] = $selection;

include "views/confirmation.php";
```

Try coding your HTML/PHP this way:

```
<?php
/* confirmation.php */

session_start();
$_SESSION[$selectedCandidate] = $selection;

require_once("../partials/header.php");

//This is where the error occurs (on my selection variable):
echo <<<_STRT
    <h1>Thanks For Your Vote!!</h1><br>
    <h2>You voted for $selection</h2>      
    <p><a href="results.php">View Results</a></p>
_STRT;

require_once("../partials/footer.php");
?>
```

I essentially eliminated a lot of start/stop code. The start of your PHP recalls the session and variable. Then I go into the HTML portion to provide the results to your site visitor.  Give it a shot. Comment on it if it doesn't resolve your issue so we can rethink it.

Comment: I was including the path incorrectly at the top.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Your using the $_SESSION variable incorrectly.

Try:

voterSubmit.php:

```
<?php
$selectedCandidate = $_POST['candidateid'];

session_start();
$_SESSION['selectedCandidate'] = $selectedCandidate;


//Redirect to results page
header("Location: views/confirmation.php");
```

confirmation.php

```
<?php

session_start();
$selection = $_SESSION['selectedCandidate'];

include "views/confirmation.php";
```

Comment: @GabrielLuciano Can you var_dump($_SESSION); after session_start() in both files?

Comment: I figured it out.  I was including the wrong file path at the top of my pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think session_start() needs to be the first line after the php tag.

$_SESSION is an array.  So you need to assign it values like:
    `$_SESSION['keyname'] = $value;`

voterSubmit.php:
`<?php`
`session_start();`
`$_SESSION['selectedCandidate'] = $_POST['candidateid'];`

`//Redirect to results page`
`header("Location: views/confirmation.php");`

confirmation.php
`<?php`
`session_start();`
`$selection = $_SESSION['selectedCandidate'];`

`include "views/confirmation.php";`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues in your code :

1. `session_start()` defined in the wrong place.
2. Wrong way of assigning value to your session variable.

Answer :

1. `session_start()` should be the first thing defined **after** your php
   tag.
2. Correct way to declare session variables is : `$_SESSION["selectedCandidate"] = $selectedCandidate;` where, `$selectedCandidate` is the value to be assigned to your session variable, named `selectedCandidate`.

Answer (score 0):

You have done 2 mistakes in your code:
1. Session should be defined in starting of page it means you have to define it like this:

```
<?php 
session_start();
//php code goes here.
?>
```

2.wrong initialization of session variable .you should do it like this:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['selectedCandidate']=$selectedCandidate;
?>
```